# Приведение SQL в какой либо стандартный вид?

Tags: sql

Есть ли программы документы, которые позволяют приводить SQL Query в нормальный вид?

Select * from table as A where A.field in ("A","B","C") =>

SELECT * FROM table where table.field ="A" OR table.field="B" OR table.field="C"

Или какой-то любой вид который считается нормальным в рамках тулы

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=~tool+for+formatting+SQL+standard

Comment: @MaxU Вы путаете нормализацию и форматирование

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "нормальным видом" (да еще в городе Тула ?). Я знаю понятие нормализации в рамках приведения структуры БД к 5й нормальной форме. А оба вида запроса абсолютно равнозначны и описаны в стандарте SQL92, так что никаких поводов считать один из них "не нормальным" я не вижу

Comment: И я сильно сомневаюсь что подобное существует, ибо оно совершенно не нужно и даже вредно. от перезаписи запроса может меняться план выполнения и соответственно скорость работы. И только программист может принимать осознанное решение почему он пишет запрос именно так, как пишет

Comment: @Mike под нормальным видом я понимаю, любое валидное выражение, в которое  приводит тула. Если инструмент считает что все что через = записано в Where( Where a = 10 OR a = 11 OR a = 12) надо записывать через Between то пусть так и будет. Вот одна из статей на эту тему http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol9/p1541-chandra.pdf

Comment: @ИванГладуш инструмент не имеет права менять 10, 11, 12 на between потому что в БД могут быть значение 10.4, например, т.е. дробные. Кроме того в определенный версиях mysql были проблемы оптимизатора именно на between, запрос выполнялся гораздо дольше

Comment: Может вы еще предложите инструменту "оптимизировать" `where X+0=5` выбросив "не нужный" `+0` ? От этого некоторые запросы могут начать вместо десятых долей секунды выполняться 3 часа ... Нет, приводить запрос к любому "стандартному" виду нельзя

Comment: @Mike не соглашусь с вами. Вы говорите про перформанс, он меня не волнует я лишь хочу понять есть ли такой тул или нет.  менять 10, 11, 12 на between потому что в БД могут быть значение 10.4, например, т.е. дробные  если тип колонки целое число то можею

Comment: А в приведенной вами статье например рекомендуется приводить `IN(subquery)` к EXISTS. Что в 60% случаев приведет к изменению плана выполнения. А дальше 50/50, либо это улучшит производительность, либо ухудшит. Опять же решение за человеком, который знает статистические характеристики своих данных

Comment: @Mike Майк меня не интересует перформанс выполнения план и т.д. Меня, как и авторов статьи, интересует нормализация квери ее ПЛАН НЕ ВАЖЕН

Comment: Это я уже понял. Я даже видел что то подобное в редакторе запросов в DataWindow PowerBuilder. оно пыталось привести запрос в графический вид и при возврате обратно делало его "нормальным", что приводило к невозможности им пользоваться и все знали, что на эту кнопку нельзя нажимать, ни когда. Кроме того должны существовать переводчики диалектов, они то же должны делать что то подобное

Comment: @ИванГладуш, можете дать определение (можно ссылкой) "нормального вида" для SQL? А то как-то стыдно стало - столько лет с базами данных работал, а про "нормальный __вид__" не слышал. Переписыванием запросов (не простым форматированием) обычно занимаются оптимизаторы - результат очень сильно зависит от диалекта SQL, от доступных метаданных, статистик и т.д.

Comment: @MaxU нормальный вид это может быть что угодно. Если приложение говорит что нужно всегда использовать лефт джоин вместо райт, то пускай так и будет значит нормальный вид это когда нету райт джоинов и только лефт. Я понятно выразил свою мысль?

Comment: @ИванГладуш, если я вас правильно понял - вас мало интересует как будет выглядеть конечный результат - это будет целиком зависеть от адекватности разработчиков приложения. :-) У меня остался только один вопрос - зачем вам это?

Comment: @MaxU почитайте статью и поймете хочу сделать тоже самое http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol9/p1541-chandra.pdf, только лучше

Comment: @ИванГладуш, такую информацию, IMO, надо указывать в вопросе. Так вы ищете готовый AUTOGRADER или хотите сделать свой, только лучше?

Comment: @MaxU А что такое автогрейдер и не подскажите где его искать?

Comment: @ИванГладуш, autograder - система автоматической проверки технических заданий/работ. Часто используется в онлайн университетах, где число студентов по одному предмету может измеряться десятками тысяч. Такие системы обычно являются интеллектуальной собственностью и врядли их будут выкладывать в открытый доступ.